# Чтение вопроса как символ, а не оператор. Prolog

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

GNU Prolog.

Требуется уметь распознавать строку

```
?- береза это растение?? .
```

Оператор `это` имеет вид

```
:-op(600, xfx, это).
```

Как можно считывать второй аргумент полностью с знаками вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

> Как можно считывать второй аргумент полностью с знаками вопроса?

Допустим, у Вас есть строка ( список `integer` ): `"береза это растение??"`.

Тогда Вы можете применить предикат `read_term_ending_by_two_question_signs/2`:

```
:-op(600, xfx, это).

% Читать терм завершающийся двумя знаками вопроса
read_term_ending_by_two_question_signs( Codes_QQ, Term_QQ) :-
    remove_question_signs( Codes_QQ, Codes ),
    read_term_from_codes( Codes, Term ),
    Term = X 'это' Н,
    atom_codes( H, Codes),
    length( Codes, Length ),
    Length_QQ is Length + 2,        
    sub_atom(H_QQ, '', Length_QQ, '??', H),
    Term_QQ = X 'это' H_QQ.

% Удалить символы вопроса
remove_question_signs( [ 63, 63 ],  [] ).
remove_question_signs( [ X | Y ],  Z ) :-
     !, remove_question_signs( [ Y ],  Z ).
```